# Converting Collada to urdf

Tags: ros, urdf, collada, robot-description

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When running `rosrun urdf check_urdf my_collada.dae`, I get this error.

```
COLLADA error: Trying to load an invalid Collada version for this DOM build
```

I have looked at the source in `collada_parser` and `urdf` and cannot seem to find which version is required (I have tried 1.4.0 and 1.5.0)

I need to be publishing joints on `/tf`, so I want to convert my Collada file into an URDF, which [robot_description](http://answers.ros.org/question/33628/load-sdf-model-into-robot_description/)  requires as input.

Will this method work on a full-robot model with kinematic information, or would I have to convert each part to an urdf?

Here's a [link](https://collada.org/owl/download.php?sess=0&parent=132&expand=1&order=name&curview=0&binary=1&id=722) to an example file that gives the error

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41786/converting-collada-to-urdf/) by [phil0stine](https://answers.ros.org/users/639/phil0stine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 682 on 2012-08-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-08-19**:
Can you post the model, or a similar one that gives you the same error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Perhaps I am misunderstanding something, but as I see it you are testing a COLLADA format to see if it is URDF. They are two different formats. You can include a reference to a .dae file *within* a URDF file as a link, but .dae themselves are not URDF.

I would recommend you check out this excellent video on URDF from ROSCON
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g9WHxOpAUns

At 15:30 in the video you will see the format to include .dae into your URDF file. I've followed this, and it works perfectly. I have about 10 different mesh links in my URDF with no problems.

---

Originally posted by [dougbot01](https://answers.ros.org/users/2842/dougbot01/) with karma: 342 on 2012-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-08-20**:
Except it's possible to load a COLLADA file and construct a C++ URDF object with this library: http://www.ros.org/wiki/collada_parser

**Comment by [phil0stine](https://answers.ros.org/users/639/phil0stine/) on 2012-08-20**:
@jbohren Exactly, the ideal would be to support full kinematic chains, as mentioned [here](http://openrave-users-list.185357.n3.nabble.com/Blender-Collada-file-error-with-openrave-py-td3195486.html), but right now I am just going for a simple shape